# Ist indirekte Rede mit Konjunktiv II möglich?

Tags: subjunctive

Bislang habe ich oftmals indirekte Rede mit KII gesehen, jedoch führte ich dies immer auf Unkenntnis des Sprechers zurück. In einem Grammatikbuch las ich aber Folgendes:

> Der Politiker sagte, dass diese Entscheidung notwendig ist und zu einer Verbesserung auf dem Arbeitsmarkt führen wird
>   *Indikativ* 
> (Abstand des Sprechers zur Aussage ist gering.)
>   b) Der Politiker sagte, dass diese Entscheidung notwendig sei und zu einer Verbesserung auf dem Arbeitsmarkt führen werde.
>   *Konjunktiv I* 
> (neutralste Form der Wiedergabe)
>   **c) Der Politiker sagte, dass diese Entscheidung notwendig wäre und zu einer Verbesserung
>   auf dem Arbeitsmarkt führen würde.
>   *Konjunktiv II* 
> (Abstand zur Aussage ist am größten)**

Da ich solch eine Regel sonst nie gesehen habe, ging ich davon aus, dass dies eher die subjektive Wertung des Autors ist.

**Kann man indirekte Rede auch mit KII zum Ausdruck bringen oder nicht?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wie Zac67 richtig sagt, ist die Verwendung des Konjunktiv II bei der indirekten Rede erlaubt. Dies empfehle ich besonders dann, wenn du als Sprecher andeuten willst, dass du das Zitierte in Zweifel ziehst oder für unwahr hältst.

> - Der Bewerber sagte, es gäbe keinen Besseren als ihn.
> - Er sagte, er wäre der Größte.
> - Mein Lehrer sagte, wenn Raumschiffe zu eng wären, läge das an der geringen Körpergröße der Ingenieure.

Comment: Ich erkenne an sich keine Steigerung des "ich glaube das nicht", wenn man K2 statt K1 verwendet. "Der Angeklagte sagte, er habe den Mord nicht begangen" hört sich für mich genauso geglaubt oder ungeglaubt an wie "der Angeklagte sagte, er hätte den Mord nicht begangen"

Answer (score 4):

> Der Politiker sagte, dass diese Entscheidung notwendig wäre und zu einer Verbesserung auf dem Arbeitsmarkt führen würde.

Dieser Satz ist einwandfrei möglich (und noch nicht mal unüblich).

Comment: Laut @Pollitzer, der die bessere Antwort gegeben hat, sollten wir immer an den Politikern zweifeln :)

Answer (score 2):

Das ist an sich eine Stil- oder stark meinungsgeprägte Frage.

Ja, es ist prinzipiell möglich, indirekte Rede mit dem Konjunktiv II auszudrücken. In manchen Fällen ist es sogar empfehlenswert:

- Wenn das Verb in der 2. Person (du, ihr) steht. Dort ist der Konjunktiv 1 einigermaßen ungebräuchlich und hört sich sehr gekünstelt an, dann nimmt man lieber den Konjunktiv 2 oder die Ersatzform mit "würde":

  > Er sagte, du hättest mich besucht

  statt der eher ungebräuchlichen Form (Konjunktiv 1)

  > Er sagte, du habest mich besucht

  oder

  > Sie meinte, du wärst schon weg

  statt

  > Sie meinte, du seiest schon weg
- Wenn Konjunktiv 1 und Indikativ gleich aussehen - dann nimmt man lieber den Konjunktiv 2:

  > Ich sagte, ich hieße Fritz

  statt

  > Ich sagte, ich heiße Fritz

Dann gibt es aber auch Fälle, in denen die Form des Konjunktiv 2 sehr ungebräuchlich ist - Dann nimmt man lieber den Konjunktiv 1 oder die Ersatzform mit "würde":

Lieber nicht (Konjunktiv 2):

> Ich dachte, der Rhein flösse in die Ostsee

sondern besser (Konjunktiv 1)

> Ich dachte, der Rhein fließe in die Ostsee

oder eher

> Ich dachte, der Rhein würde in die Ostsee fließen.

Diese ungebräuchliche Bildung des Konjunktiv 2, wo man lieber einen Konjunktiv 1 nimmt, betrifft meistens unregelmäßige Verben mit Umlaut:

*träfe, klänge, stäche, schwämme, verlöre, ...*

Was man lieber nicht tun sollte, ist Konjunktiv 1 und 2 in einer indirekten Rede zu mischen. Ich finde, das hört sich komisch an, ist aber auch Geschmackssache:

> Sie sagte, du habest mich besucht und wärst zu lang geblieben.